# how to use cereal_port in ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello
I use "sudo apt-get ros-electric-serial-communication" to install serial-communication in my computer. And I use the example code

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <cereal_port/CerealPort.h>

  ....
```

But the code can't be compiled, the error is: cereal_port/CerealPort.h:no such file or directory.

Can anyone help me with my problem? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52427/how-to-use-cereal_port-in-ros/) by [luxifu1989](https://answers.ros.org/users/3827/luxifu1989/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error is to be fixed in your CMakeLists.txt file and manifest.xml.

As the Page here says: http://ros.org/wiki/cereal_port

"make sure you have the serial_communication stack installed and don't forget to add cereal_port as a dependency on your package"

So install ros-fuerte-serial-communication unless you already have, then add

```
<depend package="cereal_port" />
```

to your manifest.xml. That should do the trick.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0